# "xml find" is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I currently have the following ajax call which runs successfully:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "services/orders/<%=OrderServices.Action.BULK_SUPPLIER_DISCOUNT%>",
            data: params,
            complete: function(xhr) {
                if (ajax.fullCheck(xhr, "delete your selected item")) {
                    unsavedChanges = false;
                }
                var xml = xhr.responseXML;
            updateAutoTotalsFromXml(xml);

            }
        });
```

variable "xml" returns:

```
<Response><Totals><FixedCost>0</FixedCost><FixedPrice>0</FixedPrice><VarCost>70.4900</VarCost><VarPrice>224.87</VarPrice></Totals><Success/></Response>
```

however when i get to here, i get the error Uncaught TypeError: xml.find is not a function.

```
function updateAutoTotalsFromXml(xml) {
        console.log(xml);
        curFixedCost = parseFloat(xml.find("FixedCost").text());
        curFixedPrice = parseFloat(xml.find("FixedPrice").text());
        curVarCost = parseFloat(xml.find("VarCost").text());
        curVarPrice = parseFloat(xml.find("VarPrice").text());
    }
```

ideas?

Comment: What do you expect that `.find()` thing to be? The error is telling you that there is no such function.

Comment: .find() is a jquery function which should find the text for FixedPrice etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [jQuery.parseXML()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/):

> Parses a string into an XML document.
>
> jQuery.parseXML uses the native parsing function of the browser to create a valid XML Document. This document can then be passed to jQuery to create a typical jQuery object that can be traversed and manipulated.

You can convert the xml to a jqueryObject and only after you can use the find function:

```js
var xml = '<Response><Totals><FixedCost>0</FixedCost><FixedPrice>0</FixedPrice><VarCost>70.4900</VarCost><VarPrice>224.87</VarPrice></Totals><Success/></Response>';

function updateAutoTotalsFromXml(xml) {
  console.log(xml);
  var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
  var jqObj = $(xmlDoc);
  curFixedCost = parseFloat(jqObj.find("FixedCost").text());
  curFixedPrice = parseFloat(jqObj.find("FixedPrice").text());
  curVarCost = parseFloat(jqObj.find("VarCost").text());
  curVarPrice = parseFloat(jqObj.find("VarPrice").text());

  console.log('curFixedCost: ' + curFixedCost +
              ' curFixedPrice: ' + curFixedPrice +
              ' curVarCost: ' + curVarCost +
              ' curVarPrice: ' + curVarPrice)
}


updateAutoTotalsFromXml(xml);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```